# Change User Name In Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have an Azure Active Directory (AAD) set up in my Azure subscription associated with an email address of mine, which we'll call `A`.

Some time later, I updated my Microsoft Account to use a new email address `B` as the primary email address, with `A` being associated with it still so it can still be used and the two email addresses treated as being one.

In AAD there is one user, whose user Id is `A` which appears not to be able to be changed as it is greyed-out. Attempting to add `B` fails with the error: **You cannot add yourself**.

Is there a way I can force the user name of the AAD user to be `B` instead of `A`?

The reason I ask is because I am trying to setup an Azure Key Vault in my subscription as it appears to be failing because whether or not I sign in as `A` or `B` in Azure Powershell, I am always signed in as `B`. This then causes this error message, which I appear to be unable to work around:

`New-AzureKeyVault : Cannot find the Active Directory object 'B' in tenant
'{Tenant Id}'. Please make sure that the user or application service principal you are
authorizing is registered in the current subscription's Azure Active directory. The TenantID displayed by the cmdlet
'get-AzureSubscription -current' is the current subscription's Azure Active directory.`

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that you are using the latest bits for Key Vault PowerShell?
I talked with some folks internally and we believe that an experience like this may be expected if you are using an older version of the PowerShell CMDLETs, but the lastest version should be update to date and not run into the issue you are having.

If you find that you still hit this issue after upgrading, we may have a bug on our side that we should fix.

In that case, my suggestion is for you to create a new Admin User. Then delete the old Admin Account (you may need to Transfer Onwership of your AAD Subscription to the new Admin), and then recreate your account, which will pull the lastest information from that user.

However, I only reccommend trying this after having updated the PowerShell bits.

Please let us know if either of these methods resolves your issues.
Thanks,
Shawn Tabrizi

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I'll check that shortly and get back to you.

Comment: I've just tried this out having updated the Azure Powershell cmdlets and still have the same issue. I'm quite wary of having to transfer the ownership of my subscription just to get this working.

Version, for reference:

```
PS> (get-module azureresourcemanager).version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
0      9      7      -1
```

Comment: Let me reach out to the owners of Key Vault cmdlets in Azure PowerShell and I will try to get back to you in a timely manner. I agree that transfering ownerhip of your subscription is a little fishy, but we believe that readding the account will pull the latest email as your primary account email. I cant think of another way to initiate a similar update.

Comment: FYI for the time being I worked around this by creating a new Microsoft Account and temporarily making it a Global Administrator of my subscription.